# C++ function template argument deduction guide

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function and a simple class

```
template <class T, class U>
int foo(T t, U u) {
   return t + u;
}

template <class A, class B>
class C : public A {
  ...
};

C<something, something> c1;
foo(c1, c1);
```

In the call of `foo` with an instance of `C`, I would like the template argument to be derived to `A`, the base class of `C`.
When creating a deduction guide like below, it fails to compile with `error: expected initializer`.

```
template <typename U, typename T, typename V>
int foo(C<U,T>, V) -> int foo<U, V>(U, V);
```

I failed to find any advise for what would be the syntactically correct way of providing such a deduction guide. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Functions can't have deduction guides.  Sounds like you want a template template or a specialization.

Comment: Does `foo<A, A>(c1, c1)` not do what you want? Note that `foo` is taking it's argument by value so you'd be copying a `C` into an `A` and thus presumably losing some of what make the subclass useful. Perhaps you want to change it to `int foo(T& t, U& u)` instead?

Comment: Even if you could do this, you shouldn't. It would be extremely confusing to a reader of the code if `foo` had a special case where calling it with `C` objects would slice them into `A`'s.